# Extract a number within a string

Tags: python, string, dataframe, extract

I have a string that looks like this:

```
T/12345/C  
T/153460/613
```

I would like to extract the number between the slash `/` i.e. `12345` and `153460`. Sometimes I have 5 numbers, sometimes 6 or more.

I tried `df[2:7]` which extracts from the second to the seventh element but i don't know where to stop as sometimes I have 5 or 6 numbers.
How can I extract the number please?

Comment: What have you tried? Like, do know [how to use regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)? or maybe [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: *"`df[:2]` which takes the second element"* -- Did you mean `[2]`? Cause `[:2]` is a *slice* up to the third element, e.g. `'abcde'[:2]` -> `'ab'`.

Comment: Is `df` a dataframe? If you're using Pandas or another dataframe library, you should add the tag for it. Pandas works very differently from plain Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Convert the string to a list.
string = "T/12345/C"
lyst = string.split("/")

print(lyst)

# Get number from the list
number = lyst[1]
print(number)

string = 'T/153460/613'
lyst = string.split("/")

print(lyst)

# Get number from the list
number = lyst[1]
print(number)
```

Output

```
['T', '12345', 'C']
12345
['T', '153460', '613']
153460
```